# Can a merge change the commits history of a branch?

Tags: git, merge

Apparently it can, see [here](http://www.jarrodspillers.com/git/2009/08/19/git-merge-vs-git-rebase-avoiding-rebase-hell.html) - at least this is the way I see it.

Before merge. The remote branch `master` at `origin` is on the left. Both branches are the same.

[image]

Now suppose both me and my friend have done some work, and my friend pushed his work first to the remote branch, and I have commited my work locally.

[image]

In this case I can't simply `git push`, because that would cause `commited by other` to be removed from the remote repo (I think I could do `git push -f for that, but again - that would overwrite my friend's commit).

The article suggests that `git pull origin master` (which `fetch`es the changes from the `origin` repo's `master` branch and `merge`s it into my local `master` branch) rewrites the history of commits in my local `master` branch! How can it be? I thought a merge can only create a new merge commit, without altering the existing commits. But in this case, the commits order has changed - now the `commited by other` comes first, **then** my `local commit`.

So, knowing that pull is the same as fetch (which updates the remote-tracking branch `origin/master` that is stored locally on my PC) followed by merging the updated `origin/master` into the local branch `master`, would it produce the same result in this case - would that merge alter the order of past commits in the local `master` branch?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But in this case, the commits order has changed - now the commited by other comes first, then my local commit.

This is not true - your local commit and the "committed by other" are *peers*, or siblings. The new merge commit has them both as parents. Does that make sense? Your commit history is not changed in the least.

I cannot seem to access the site you posted, but the title in the url refers to merging **and rebasing**, and avoiding "rebase hell". Rebasing does indeed change your history; perhaps that is what the author was talking about.

**Edit in response to comment**: If you have `A-B-C` locally and `A-B-D` on the remote, after a fetch and merge your local will look like:

```
A--B--C--M
   \--D-/
```

In other words, both `C` and `D` will have `B` as a parent, and both `C` and `D` will be parents of `M`. After you push, the remote branch will also look like this.

Now at first, you may think, "so my history *does* change, because `B` used to have one child, and now it has two". But git does not store pointers to children, it only stores pointers to parents. And `C` still has the single parent `B`, so your history did not change. And since `D` still has the single parent `B`, the remote's history did not change either.

Comment: To clarify: many Git clients will list commits in chronological order. This can give the *appearance* that history has changed after a merge since the commits will be listed intermingled. In reality, @David Deutsch is correct, the history remains in tact. Most Git clients will offer some sort of graph tree to help distinguish this, but they can be difficult to decipher.

Comment: This link doesn't work for you? Weird... http://www.jarrodspillers.com/git/2009/08/19/git-merge-vs-git-rebase-avoiding-rebase-hell.html

Comment: @user5539357 it does now. Nowhere does he state that `merge` changes your history, but his image showing the "other commit" below the local commit is indeed misleading. I would use a tool like Source Tree, which does a good job of showing the history as it really is.

Comment: If the remote branch was `A-B-D` and I had `A-B-C` locally, after fetch and merge it will be `A-B-C-M` locally (M is a merge commit with parents C and D). So if I push it, the remote branch will be `A-B-D-M` (because `A-B-D` is an ancestor of my merge commit `M`)?

Comment: So the graph you posted in edit is still a single branch, even though it contains commits that have multiple parents? For some reason I thought only things like `A-B-C-D-E` are considered a branch... but branch is just a pointer to a commit anyway.

Comment: Well as you say, a branch is just a pointer to a commit, so technically there are at least two branches, the local and remote one. But they are both pointing to the same commit (`M`), and one is the "upstream" branch of the other, so I would consider it a single branch.

Answer (score 1):

What David said is true, the two commits are siblings and the merge commit is their child. However, if you do want to functionality where the remote commit is pulled down "under" your local commit, you can do `git pull --rebase` which will pull down all remote commits and then replay yours on top of them without the merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

A *merge* takes two or more branches, and creates a commit that interleaves the changes in all parents (resolving conflicts, as needed; the user has to decide how). `git` does not change history by itself.

To change history, you have to request that explicitly, via `git rebase` or other commands explicitly designed for such surgery. Needless to say, they are dangerous, and must be used with utmost care.